# Android Google Maps V2 Remove Single Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this question has been asked previously But I did not understand that particular answer..there is an option of adding marker but no option for removing marker..

Please help me .. If you know

Also specify the coding for that one

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can get the markers reference when you add it to the map. The marker class has a remove() method.

```
googleMap = fm.getMap();
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(..);
marker.remove();
```

If you want to clear all markers you can use the clear() method.

```
googleMap.clear();
```

Comment: there is no method like remove() . And I dont want to clear the map because it will clear my tracking route also ...

Comment: Look into the docs and you will find it. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove()